# I needed to find the impulse response of the low-pass RC filter described by the differential equation and the output

Tags: filter, transfer-function, output, low-pass

[image]

If someone could check it, that would be great.

Comment: The first block is not LTI, you have to use the integral.

Comment: to add to what @aconcernedcitizen  said. To answer the second part of the question, OP can simply square the input \$2 e^{-t}u(t) \rightarrow 4 e^{-2t}u(t)\$ and then find *its* Laplace transform. Then feed that result into the second system whose transfer function is already calculated by OP. Then take inverse Laplace transform.

Comment: ok thank you I will try with squaring the input